# How can I List unique characters in a dictionary and store them as a set?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, set

I am trying to list unique characters in a dictionary and store them as a set. The dictionary has the following fields

> ID,Name, Description, Type Price.

I need to list the unique categories in "Type" field

```py
content=("C:\\Users\\jon.welsh\\Desktop\\ebyayproducts.json", "r")
for item in ebayproducts:
    values = set([i['Type'] for i in content])

# and then I get this Error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you don't open the file - you just create a tuple `content` that contains 2 string values.

To open a file, parse the json you can do:

```py
import json

with open("C:\\Users\\jon.welsh\\Desktop\\ebyayproducts.json", "r") as f_in:
    content = json.load(f_in)

values = set(i["Type"] for i in content)
print(values)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and got the followingTypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: @Deslar457 Don't use `json.loads()`, use `json.load()` (without `s`) as in the example